# Can't find GridView in ASP

Tags: asp.net, shopping-cart

I am brand new to asp and downloaded some example code of a shopping cart. When I created a new project in Visual Studio, added all the files in and tried to compile I got the following error.

> Error 1   The name 'gvShoppingCart' does not exist in the current context c:\users\slaphappysmoker\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Shopcart\Shopcart\ViewCart.aspx.cs   21  3   Shopcart

However I can see where gvShoppingCart gets defined in the ViewCart.aspx file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ViewCart.aspx.cs" Inherits="ViewCart" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <link href="Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
            <a href="Default.aspx">&lt; Back to Products</a>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvShoppingCart" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="There is nothing in your shopping cart." GridLines="None" Width="100%" CellPadding="5" ShowFooter="true" DataKeyNames="ProductId" OnRowDataBound="gvShoppingCart_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvShoppingCart_RowCommand">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" BackColor="#3D7169" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" BackColor="#6C6B66" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F8F8F8" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuantity" Columns="5" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnRemove" Text="Remove" CommandName="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductId") %>' style="font-size:12px;"></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Price" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPrice" HeaderText="Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdateCart" Text="Update Cart" OnClick="btnUpdateCart_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code that is calling the GridView in the ViewCart.aspx.cs file:

```
protected void BindData() {
    // Let's give the data to the GridView and let it work!
    // The GridView will take our cart items one by one and use the properties
    // that we declared as column names (DataFields)
    gvShoppingCart.DataSource = ShoppingCart.Instance.Items;
gvShoppingCart.DataBind();
}
```

How can I get the ViewCart.aspx.cs code file to recognize the ViewCart.aspx and the GridView contained within?

Edit: Added the function that calls the gridview.

Comment: Where is the code located, specifically which function?  There are several functions that run when a page is loaded, some are before the elements are created and some are after.

Comment: Any duplicated class names or duplicated namespace names?

Comment: None that I can see. The only errors from the compiler are all gvSHoppingCart can't be found.

Comment: Re-start Visual Studio, clean and rebuild your project and give it a go! :)

Comment: perhaps it is a webapp project and the designer.cs file is messed up.
try deleting the designer.cs file for this page and right clicking the aspx file is solution explorer and selecting convert to web app

Comment: Include your viewcart.aspx.cs code so we can check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make sure that the gridview has a reference in the designer.cs file

`protected global :: System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView gvShoppingCart;`

Comment: I did that and it built but then gave the error CS0102: The type 'ViewCart' already contains a definition for 'gvShoppingCart'

Comment: You might need to convert the solution from a Web Site to Web Application, in order to see the code-behind before runtime.